# Javascript link read

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

how can I get only the link?

```
<a id="skip" href="http://google.de">
```

This doenst work:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('skip');
var array = doc ? doc.getElementsByTagName('a')  : [
];
if (array.length > 2)
array[0].href = array[1].href;
alert(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `doc` will never be an array as `document.getElementById` will only return the matched element, or undefined.

This code is all you need:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('skip');
alert(doc.href);
```

---

**Extra:**

This conditional statement would return the element, and never be false:

```
var array = doc ? doc.getElementsByTagName('a') : [];
```

This would always return false as the html element does not have a `.length` property:

```
if(array.length > 2)
```

This will cause an error as `array` is not an array.

```
alert(array[0]);
```